# Meaning of "give ground (to somebody)"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, expressions

In the following self-made sentence does the bold part mean "let someone to play in order to demonstrate his / her abilities":

> I am really grateful to the coach; he overlooked my mistake against the opposing team in the final game and **gave ground to me** again.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that it can have this meaning? Have you heard it used, or seen it used, in this way?

Comment: In sports, we would say "he tried me out again" or "he put me back in the game" or "put me back on the field."

Comment: @TRomano yes; I have a south American friend; once I asked him; he told me such thing long time ago.

Comment: Actually my question is not about letting someone be back on the field; it is about giving them an opportunity and let them demonstrate their capabilities on the ground.

Answer (score 3):

*Give ground* cannot be used in this way. From Collins English Dictionary:

> [**give ground**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/give-ground)
>   to draw back or retreat:
>   "*But as more and more men crossed the drawbridge, the castle defenders were forced to give ground*"
>   "*She leaned over his desk, pushing her face towards his, stopping uncomfortably close as he refused to give ground.*"

You may be thinking of a somewhat similar phrase, *to give centre stage* (from Merriam-Webster):

> [**center stage**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/center%20stage)
>   The middle section of a theater's stage:
>   "*The actor stood alone at center stage.*"
>
> A main or very important position:
>   "*As we wrap up work on the old project, a new one moves to center stage.*"
>   "*The issue is expected to take center stage in the elections.*"

It is not uncommon to give someone an important position so that they can demonstrate that they are capable of performing in that position.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see what you mean; I guess there is no such a thing in English at all (at least in this way). Thanks again.